# How do I build from different locations in my tree with multiple SConstruct files that use Repositories?

Tags: build, scons

I've got the following directory structure:

```
root/
  SConstruct
  item0/
    SConstruct
    unit0/
      unit0.h
      private/
        unit0.c
      test/
        test_unit0.c
        SConstruct
        SConscript
    unit1/
      (repeat unit0 structure)
  item1/
    (repeat item0 structure)
```

I want to be able to run scons from `root` to build all things below it, and from `root/item0` to build all things below it, etc.

The top-level SConstruct looks like:

```
SConscript('item0/SConstruct', duplicate=0)
SConscript('item1/SConstruct', duplicate=0)
```

The item-level SConstruct:

```
SConscript('unit0/SConstruct', duplicate=0)
SConscript('unit1/SConstruct', duplicate=0)
```

The unit-level SConstruct:

```
import os

proj_root = os.path.abspath('../../../../..')
proj_shared_path = os.path.join(proj_root,
    os.path.normpath('trunk/sys/shared'))

env = Environment()
SConscript(
    'SConscript',
    variant_dir='output',
    exports=['env', 'proj_shared_path'],
    duplicate=0)
```

The unit-level SConscript (important stuff only):

```
Import('*')
# Setup Repositories to access out-of-current-directory-tree files.
lib1_path = os.path.join(proj_shared_path, 'lib1')
env.Repository('#/../private', lib1_path)

# Set general compilation and link flags.
env.Append(
    CFLAGS = '-Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic',
    CPPPATH = ['#/../..', proj_shared_path])

# These are the files we don't need to run gcovr on.
non_cov_srcs = [
    'testit.c',
    'lib1.c'
    ]

# Create a 'coverage' environment to build files that we will run gcovr on.
cov = env.Clone()
cov.Append(CFLAGS = '--coverage -O0')
cov_srcs = cov.Object('unit0.c')
SideEffect('unit0.gcno', cov_srcs)

# Our unit test program combines all the sources we've listed so far.
test_exe = env.Program(
    'test_unit0',
    [cov_srcs, non_cov_srcs],
    LIBS='gcov', LINKFLAGS='--coverage')
```

Now, this all works fine when I run scons from `root/item0/unit0/test`. However, when I run from `root` or `root/item0`, I get various types of errors, like below (run from `root/item0`):

```
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: *** [unit0\test\output\unit0.obj] Source 'unit0\test\unit0.c' not found, needed by target 'unit0\test\output\unit0.obj'.
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Clearly `unit0\test\unit0.c` won't be found because it doesn't exist, but I'm not sure why scons thinks it has to be there since the Repository is defined as `'#/../private'` and there is no private shown in the error message.

**edit** I've figured out that it's probably looking for `unit0\test\unit0.c` because `unit0\test` is the "root" directory for `SConscript`. I'm also guessing that the `#/../private` `Repository` location is only correct when `scons` is run from `unit0\test`. But, when I try to specify the `Repository` in any other way (including an absolute path built with `os.path.abspath` (and verified to be correct)), `scons` still doesn't seem to want to look there for `unit0.c`. Why is that?

Comment: Why not use SCons -U? That should do what you want..

Comment: @bdbaddog I wasn't aware of that option to `scons`. Reading the docs, I'm not certain how that solves my problem. It would seem to allow me to run `scons -U` from `root/item0/unit0/test` and have just that `SConscript` executed. But, I don't see how it addresses the error I am getting when running `scons` from `root/item0` as show in my question. Can you help me understand how `scons -U` would work for this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With further help from @bdbaddog in the #scons IRC channel, I was able to determine the following:

1. What I was actually trying to achieve was ensuring the build artifacts for each source ended up in my `variant_dir`
2. With `SConstruct` and `SConscript` in the same directory, `Repository` ended up achieving this when building from the `unit0/test` directory. But, I didn't know why.

To properly achieve (1), `Repository` is not the right tool. Instead, `SConscript` should look like this:

```
Import('*')

# Set general compilation and link flags.
env.Append(
    CFLAGS = '-Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic',
    CPPPATH = ['#/item0', '#/lib1'])

# These are the files we don't need to run gcovr on.
non_cov_objs = [
    Object(target='testit', source='testit.c'),
    Object(target='lib1', source='#/lib1/lib1.c'
    ]

# Create a 'coverage' environment to build files that we will run gcovr on.
cov = env.Clone()
cov.Append(CFLAGS = '--coverage -O0')
cov_objs = cov.Object(
    target='unit0', 
    source='#/item0/unit0/private/unit0.c')
SideEffect('unit0.gcno', cov_srcs)

# Our unit test program combines all the sources we've listed so far.
test_exe = env.Program(
    'test_unit0',
    [cov_objs, non_cov_objs],
    LIBS='gcov', LINKFLAGS='--coverage')
```

By specifying `target` and `source` for each `Object`, I can achieve what I want in terms of the object files (and other side-effects) being generated in the `variant_dir`.